# How can I display a random cat image from an API on my webpage using async-await in JavaScript and HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, async-await

I am writing a program which calls from an API to get a random cat image. I want to be able to display that image on my webpage and not just display the url in the console.

//This is my html (It is really basic but I just want to get the output to work)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Cat Gif</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h1>This is a random image of a cat!</h1>
    </div>

    <script src="catGif.js">
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

//This is my javascript

```
let container = document.querySelector(".container");
    async function apiFunction() {
        await fetch("https://api.thecatapi.com/v1/images/search")
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then((result) => {
                //items = result;
                let img = document.createElement("img");
                img.src = result[0].url;
                container.appendChild(img);

            }),
            (error) => {
                console.log(error);
            }
    }
```

Comment: Okay, and what about this is not working as intended ...?

Comment: Your code works, but you have to call the function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not call your defined function.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Cat Gif</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h1>This is a random image of a cat!</h1>
    </div>

    <script>
        let container = document.querySelector(".container");
        async function apiFunction() {
            await fetch("https://api.thecatapi.com/v1/images/search")
                .then(res => res.json())
                .then((result) => {
                    //items = result;
                    let img = document.createElement("img");
                    img.src = result[0].url;
                    container.appendChild(img);
                }),
                (error) => {
                    console.log(error);
                }
        }
        // Call the function
        apiFunction();
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```